# Is dispatch_after more efficient than NSTimer when used in large quantities?

Tags: ios, nstimer, dispatch-after

Which is more efficient? The biggest difference is you can't cancel dispatch_after blocks from executing while you can with NSTimer. So which is better: a large number of dispatch_after blocks that can't be canceled or a large number of NSTimers that will be canceled when possible?

Comment: Benchmark your scenario and go with whatever seems best.  It is unlikely that the performance characteristics greatly favor one over the other, so you need to weigh the other considerations after having hard data.

Comment: How would I go about benchmarking the two?

Comment: @TonyFriz: I suggest that you use Xcode's [unit testing features](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UnitTesting.html).

Comment: I see XCTest incudes performance testing but how does that help me measure the difference between a lot of timers vs a lot of dispatch blocks? I want to see how a bunch of scheduled timers hurts the app in general. Is there a way to test that with unit testing?

Comment: I could measure the part of actually scheduling the timers but isn't there still a deficit while they're waiting to fire?